# Want to create separate page for each blog post in django?But dont know how to proceeed?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a blog app with django.I have a home page in my app where all blog posts will be displayed.If anyone clicks on a blog post it should be displayed on a separate page.But dont know how to proceed?

I know that i cant create separate html page for each post.I created a common layout html page for displaying each post.But dont know know how to add that content to it.

```
 <!---------layout.html---->
  {% load static %}
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Self Learn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static ' 
                                                 styles/main.css' %}" />
 </head>
 <body>    
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="logo">Blog</h1> 
        <ul class="menu">
            <a href="/">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a>Hi,{{user.username}}</a>
            <a href="logout">Logout</a>
            {% else %}
            <a href="login">Login</a>
            <a href='register'>Register</a>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
     </div>
     <a href="newpost">
        <img src="{% static 'images\12.PNG' %}" class="logo1"/>
     </a>
     <!----Post------>
     {% for blog in blog %}
     <div class="list">
        <div class="con">
            <h3 style="color:DodgerBlue;">{{blog.author}}</h3>
            <h6 style="font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;"> {{blog.date}} 
                                                                    </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="con">
            <a href='indpost'><h1><b>{{blog.title}}</b></h1></a>
        </div>
        <div class="con">
            <p>{{blog.desc}}</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     {% endfor %}
     {% block content %}
     {% endblock %}
 </body>
 </html>
    from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
    from blog.models import Post
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
    from django.contrib import messages

    # Create your views here.
    def homepage(request):
        blogs= Post.objects.all()
        return render(request,'layout.html',{'blog':blogs})

    def register(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            email=request.POST['email']
            User_name=request.POST['User_name']
            Password1=request.POST['Password1']
            Password2=request.POST['Password2']
            if Password1 == Password2:
                if User.objects.filter(username=User_name).exists():
                    messages.info(request,'Username Taken')
                    return redirect('register')
                elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.info(request,'Email Taken')
                    return redirect('register')
                else:
                    user = 
 User.objects.create_user(username=User_name,password=Password1,email=email)
                    user.save();
                    return redirect('/')
            else:
                messages.info(request,'Password Not Matching')
        else:
            return render(request,'register.html')

    def login(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            User_name=request.POST['User_name']
            Password=request.POST['Password']
            user = auth.authenticate(username=User_name,password=Password)
            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request,user)
                return redirect("/")
            else:
                messages.info(request,"invalid")
                redirect('login')
        else: 
            return render(request,'Login.html')

    def logout(request):
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('login')

    def newpost(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.method == "POST":
                title = request.POST['title']
                desc=request.POST['desc']
                insert = 
                Post(title=title,desc=desc,author_id=request.user.username)
                insert.save();
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                return render(request,'Newpost.html')
        else:
            return redirect('login')

    def indpost(request):
        return render(request,'indpost.html')

  #urls.py
    from django.urls import path,include
    from . import views

    urlpatterns=[
            path('',views.homepage),
            path('register',views.register,name='register'),
            path('login',views.login,name='login'),
            path('logout',views.logout,name='logout'),
            path('newpost',views.newpost,name="newpost"),
            path('indpost',views.indpost,name="indpost"),
    ]
```

Comment: This template is not at all relevant. Where are you views and URLs?

Comment: i added views and urls in my code section

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to get a specific article with it's slug and other options in models.py:

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
     return reverse('singlepage',
            args=[self.slug])
```

where singlepage is the name of your view to deal with the request,

You can add a view to pass the requested url as a context and render the generic template in the following manner:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, reverse    
def singlepage (request, slug) :
    article = get_object_or_404(<model_name>, slug=post, status='published')
    return render(request,'news/singlepage.html',{'article': article})
```

You can add the reference to the url in the urls.py as well like :

```
path('<slug:post>/',views.singlepage,name='singlepage')
```

Then in your html you can access the article context and refer to it's title as `{{ article.title }}` and so forth

hope this helps

you can refer to the blog application on this link: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-2-by-Example/tree/master/Chapter01/mysite

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking it's called Detail View and you can achieve it with many ways. I would suggest to use the Detail Class View from Django.

[Here is the link to the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)

Also if you want to do with with function based views you can check my [blog I have created](https://github.com/Belonias/personal-site/tree/master/src/posts)